# RFID Applications

Tags: rfid

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to both modify a passive RFID tag's information and also store current values before changing them. The Pi is a must because I use it for tons of other functions in the same machine.  My problem is that the tag is about a foot and half away from the Pi and circuitry and therefore need an antenna to both read from and write to a passive tag that far away.  Is there any solution?  I'm willing to buy off the shelf, not just design my own because I'm really new to this topic.

Comment: How about a metric tonne more detail else you will likely hear "anything is possible"

Comment: Why can't you just run a suitable cable between the RPi and the actual card reader?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will definitely work with RAIN RFID (also known as UHF RFID). With this technology you are able to read and write tags feet away. Although it may not be compatible with the RFID technology you have in mind right now.

You can find a compatible product here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14066.